# While creating VM in Oracle virtual Box error "the hardware virtualization is enabled in the acceleration section" occurring

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

While trying to Create VM using Oracle virtual box, error "the hardware virtualization is enabled in the acceleration section" is showing on the UI and while trying to select OS versions only 32 bit OS list is shown;
OS Version : windows 10 17134
After creating 32 bit Linux ubuntu VM, while starting it, error "The virtual machine 'Linux32' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1" appeared with Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Following steps have been performed to resolve the problem not problem still not resolved;

It is verified virtualization enabled in BIOS (VT-X and VT-d) enabled

In windows 10 control panel -> Programs -> turn windows features on or off -> Hyper-V is not enabled

Also tried to enable and disable Hyper-V from windows features on or off

From the Admin command prompt run the command : bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Windows start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security  > Device Security -> core isolation is also disabled

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting in Oracle VB is actually telling you that the machine needs that feature to be turned on.... Since its off, in response to enabled acceleration in settings... it is detecting that the the Parent/Host os is missing the acceleration hardware feature.

Turn it on then try again.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is enabling Virtualization Technology in BIOS setup. I understand not all computers have this option in bios but toggling it on may resolve the issue.

Another solution that appears to work for others (windows users) is toggling the settings on Hyper-V in windows features (Turn Windows Features on/off).

This is one error that can be challenging to solve.